# Combinatorics Binomial How to prove it?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

$$
\sum_{k=n}^{2n} \binom{k}{n} 2^{-k}=1
$$
Anyone can help me?
**How to prove it?**

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you, for instance, done any manipulations that look like they ought to make it easier? Have you checked that the result is true for some small values of $n$? Anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the convention that $\binom{k}{n}=0$ if $k<n$ we can deduce:

$\begin{aligned}\sum_{k\leq2n}\binom{k}{n}2^{-k} & =\sum_{k\leq2n}\left[\binom{k-1}{n-1}+\binom{k-1}{n}\right]2^{-k}\\
 & =\sum_{k\leq2n}\binom{k-1}{n-1}2^{-k}+\sum_{k\leq2n}\binom{k-1}{n}2^{-k}\\
 & =\sum_{k\leq2n-1}\binom{k}{n-1}2^{-k-1}+\sum_{k\leq2n-1}\binom{k}{n}2^{-k-1}\\
 & =\sum_{k\leq2n-2}\binom{k}{n-1}2^{-k-1}+\binom{2n-1}{n-1}2^{-2n}+\sum_{k\leq2n}\binom{k}{n}2^{-k-1}-\binom{2n}{n}2^{-2n-1}\\
 & =\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\leq2n-2}\binom{k}{n-1}2^{-k}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\leq2n}\binom{k}{n}2^{-k}
\end{aligned}
$

The last equality implies that: $$\sum_{k\leq2n}\binom{k}{n}2^{-k}=\sum_{k\leq2n-2}\binom{k}{n-1}2^{-k}$$
so now induction can be applied to prove that $$\sum_{k\leq2n}\binom{k}{n}2^{-k}=1$$